# Edit the user via the custom method in the model

Tags: laravel

There is a field`balance` in the user table to store its inventory. I wrote a method in the user model to increase user inventory. But I'm not sure that's correct
I wrote this code but it does not work.What is the problem

```
public function addBalance($balance)
{
      return $this->balance += $balance;
}
```

Comment: you have to save the model after adjusting an attribute if you want it saved

Comment: @lagbox How to save in the model?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserts https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#updates there is also an `increment` method to increment a field by a value

Comment: @lagbox This way I have to get the user and then update its inventory. But I want it to increase like this `auth()->user()->addBalance(10000);`

Comment: you still have to call `save` at some point to actually save the record to the database (or use `increment` or `decrement`) otherwise you have only updated the attribute on the model instance